# why do some buttons in my app work on iphone and not on ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have an app which is setup as universal, using one storyboard.
In this app I have two buttons and one link. The first button is calling an in-app purchase and is working well on iPhone and iPad.

The second button and link are not working on iPad, but are working on an iPhone.

1.The following is the code used for the second button (addNameButton):
BannerViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[[BannerViewManager sharedInstance] addBannerViewController:self];

NSArray *children = self.childViewControllers;
assert(children != nil);    // must have children
// keep track of our child view controller for rotation and frame management
_contentController = children[0];
addNameButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[addNameButton addTarget:self
           action:@selector(addEvent:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[addNameButton setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//addNameButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, self.contentController.view.frame.size.height+30, 300.0, 40.0);

//addNameButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245/255.0 green:209/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:1.0];


[self.contentController.view addSubview:addNameButton];

}
```

and

```
-(IBAction)addEvent:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"%@",self.contentController);
TablesViewController * vc = (TablesViewController *)self.contentController;
[vc addUpdateAlert];
}
```

The addUpdateAlert code is in the TablesViewController.m

```
-(void)addUpdateAlert
{
[self startLoading];
NSString * name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:USERNAME];
if(name.length == 0)
{
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please Enter your friend code in the settings tab." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        alert.tag = 10;
        [alert show];
    [self startLoading];
}
else
{
    if(appDel.isInternetAvailable)
    {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(connectoDbAndPerformAction:) withObject:name];
    }
    else
    {
        [self stopLoading];
        [appDel showInternetNotAvailableAlert];
    }
}

}
```

The connectoDbAndPerformAction is executing the insert/update statement in the same TablesViewController.m

Again, the app is submitted and accepted, so live and this button is working on an iPhone.

2.The link is set up as text in the storyboard with as Behavior: Selectable and Detection: Links. Again this is working on an iPhone and not on an iPad.

What code do I have to change (or do you need to see other code as well)?

Comment: Does the method actually fire on the iPad when the button is tapped? Or nothing happens? If the latter, I think your issues is the button being out of the childView bounds. (Even though visible)

Comment: try using breakpoints to see where the code stops.

Comment: I did use breakpoints. It does not get to the points (when using my iPad). If the button is out of the childView bounds, I would not expect the iPhone work, would I?

Comment: I just made the button smaller and tested it again, unfortunately that did not solve the issue